# How to ORDER BY smallest value in 3 different columns?

Tags: mysql, select, multiple-columns

My table_a:

```
A|B|C // Columns
3|4|0 // Values
```

I want to make an select ordering by small value first..
Something like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM table_a ORDER BY (smallest of A,B,C first, second and third (Bigger one)) ASC"

returns: C=0,A=3,B=4
```

Is that possible? without using PHP or other script?

Comment: After having done the query below, it seems as if what you have asked for is not quite as expected.  Why does the column order particularly matter?  It's not really possible to do what you seem to be asking for to some degree as it would require dynamically renaming the columns.  ORDER BY relates to ordering **rows**, not columns, and so would do nothing in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a quick-and-dirty attempt but seems to get the desired result, not entirely sure why you would want to do that though.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d3ec/2

```
SELECT
    l2.A,
    l2.B,
    l2.C
FROM (
    SELECT
        l1.A,
        l1.B,
        l1.C,
        l1.smallestColumn,
        l1.largestColumn,
        CASE
            WHEN l1.A > l1.smallestColumn AND l1.A < l1.largestColumn THEN l1.A
            WHEN l1.B > l1.smallestColumn AND l1.B < l1.largestColumn THEN l1.B
            ELSE l1.C -- Fallback to C, in case of a tied result
        END AS middleColumn
    FROM (
        SELECT
            A,
            B,
            C,
            LEAST( A , B , C ) AS smallestColumn,
            GREATEST( A , B , C ) AS largestColumn
        FROM table_a
    ) l1
) l2
ORDER BY
    l2.smallestColumn,
    l2.middleColumn,
    l2.largestColumn;
```